# show one popup window at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to show only one popup at a time?

i have created one page called parent.html. On parent page, i have two links one is **register** and another is **login**.
if i click register then register page open as child window
but
if i click login then already opened child box(register) should close and login child window should open or all previously opened child box should disappear.

my code is as below

```
<input type="button" value="login" onclick="ShowPopup('login.asp')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var popup;
    function ShowPopup(url) {
        popup = window.open(url, "self", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=100,height=100,left = 490,top = 262");
        popup.focus();
    }
</script>
</form>

<input type="button" value="register" onclick="ShowPopup('register.asp')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function ShowPopup(url) {
        popup = window.open(url, "self", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=100,height=100,left = 490,top = 262");
        popup.focus();
    }
</script>
</form>
```

i replaced "popup" with "self". now only one child window open at a time instead of multi and working perfect.

**but when i close child window, parent page is not refreshing.**

child window code as below

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input type="button" value="Refresh Parent" onclick="RefreshParent()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshParent() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
</script>
</form>
```

please help me out

Comment: `"popup"` you can replace it with `"self"`.

Comment: @Jai problem solved thanx.

Answer (score 0):

First thing , there is no need to define variable & function again .. and now coming to solution as --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var popup;
    function ShowPopup(url) {
        if(popup)
        {
         popup.close();
        }
        popup = window.open(url, "Popup", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,
                menubar=no,resizable=0,width=100,height=100,left = 490,top = 262");
        popup.focus();
    }
</script>
```

In Your Child Page ,Head Section (To refresh parent window on close)

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        if(window.opener)
          window.opener.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by passing parameter to true.

**-- OR --**

You can also some code in parent while you open a child window and look up for its child window if its close refresh itself..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var popup;
     var lookupTimer=null;
        function ShowPopup(url) {
            if(popup)
            {
             popup.close();
            }
            popup = window.open(url, "Popup", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,
            statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=100,height=100,left = 490,top = 262");
            popup.focus();
            lookupTimer = setInterval(function(){ loolUpChild(); }, 1000);
        }
    function loolUpChild()
    {
        if((popup.closed))
                {
                 window.location.reload(true);
                 clearInterval(lookupTimer);
                }   

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: how to refresh parent window when child window close. code for child window i have written above.

Comment: @lokeshpurohit , congratulations at all .. you should accept an answer which may others help to find one

Comment: two more issues....can we remove title bar from child window like modal popup? and while child window opens, parent window should be masked with transplant color?

Comment: second one can be achieved by css applying on parent while the first one "you can not manipulate window as it is browser's asset"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92230/discussion-between-lokesh-purohit-and-rohit-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable and maintain your flag if previous popup is open then close first and open new
Like

```
 if(popup){
        popup.close();
        popup=false;
    }
```

after that open new

```
window.open(url, "Popup", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=100,height=100,left = 490,top = 262");
    popup = true;
```